# Downloading CVS repository generates a server connection error

Tags: ssh, eclipse-plugin, cvs, libssh2

I have an "org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ssh2..." error leading to a Connection Timeout downloading a CVS repository using extssh.

I have tried installing different versions of Eclipse, still the same Connection Timeout issue exists.

I can download other svn/git projects. Only this CVS repository has issues. I have checked my Java version and tried to pull the code using command line.

Screenshot showing the error:
[image]

When I tried to pull code from command prompt:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a firewall problem.  Go to Preferences -> General -> Network connections to set your proxies, etc.

Also, the reason this won't work on the command line is that the extssh protocol is not defined for the command line. You should be able to use `ssh` or `pserver` (for anonymous access).